# Entity Framework - Could anybody point me to a "how entity framework actually works' site?

Tags: entity-framework

Could anybody provide some details on "how entity framework actually works" or point me to a web site? I dont find any somehow.

Comment: Do you need conceptual information (what it is, why do I need it), or a how-to?

Comment: Robert, the conceptual information on how does it work and i dont get it. Honestly, not able to understand the one here > en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework

Answer (score 3):

I'm affraid that it is so complex that you can start only [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) or buy [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260).

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend Julie Lerman's book [Programming Entity Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260) (she's working on the 2nd edition which will cover EF v4) and in the meantime, check out her [Learn Entity Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20150524110523/http://learnentityframework.com:80/learnentityframework/) web site for hints, tips, tutorial and much more.

[image]

She's also doing a series of introductory screencasts at [Pluralsight On-Demand training](https://www.pluralsight.com/), which is not free, but online training well worth the price of a subscription.

Also check out the [ADO.NET team blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/) for interesting tidbits about EF from time to time.

Comment: The second edition of the book was released few days ago. I'm going to order my copy next week.